# Ho to make the Receiver operating characteristic (ROC) and identifying the Youden index

Tags: r, stata, roc

I would like to make a ROC curve and identify the Youden-Index. I have a subsample as below. Where I need to find cut point for the column "val" based on the reference column "ref". How can I make the ROC plot, identifying the cutoff with specificities and sensitivities as well as Youden Index, in Stata or R?

```
cut_= structure(list(val = c("2.5", "3.5", "1.5", "1.1", "2.4", "1.6", 
    "1.9", "2.7", "1.2", "1.5", "2.1", "1.4", "1.8", "3.5", "2.5", 
    "2.4"), ref = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
    1)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -16L))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far Lisa, and where did you get stuck? There are lots of existing Q&As about ROC curves here, and often `pROC` is the go-to package.

Comment: You may have gotten stuck because the `val` column is of type character, not numeric.

Comment: @Allan Cameron
Actually I tried to make the ROC in stata and in R is not gonna be difficult, but I dont know how to find the Youden index and different cutpoints with specifiities and sensitivities. Can you please help for this?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for `pROC::coords`.

Comment: The Youden's index for each point can be calculated by adding the sensitivity and specificity columns in the `pROC::coords` suggested by @dipetkov. (Just subtract 1 from sensitivity + specificity). The highest Youden's index will be your optimal cutoff.

Comment: @Allan Cameron @
dipetkov thanks do you mean the Youden's index optimal cutoff is: Youden's index = max(sensitivities+ specificities)-1?

Comment: Being open to solutions in different environments is fine for you, but the incentive to offer a Stata solution is vanishingly slight here. No hard feelings though....

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, it is pretty easy to obtain in R with `pROC`. You need to convert `val` to a numeric vector first, then you can create the ROC curve, let's call it `cut_roc`:

```
cut_$val <- as.numeric(cut_$val)
library(pROC)
cut_roc <- roc(cut_$ref, cut_$val)
```

Then it's as simple as a call to `coords` with `x="best"` to get the best threshold(s) (youden is the default so the last argument is optional):

```
coords(cut_roc, x="best", best.method="youden")
#   threshold specificity sensitivity
# 1      1.15       0.125       1.000
# 2      1.45       0.250       0.875
# 3      2.25       0.625       0.500
# 4      2.45       0.750       0.375
# 5      2.60       0.875       0.250
```

Note that in this specific ROC curve, multiple points of the curve maximize the Youden index.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this a comment, not an answer; see the answer by @Calimo instead.

I thought it might be interesting to plot the ROC curve with the "best" thresholds. Unfortunately, as the figure shows, the binary classifier behind this ROC curve doesn't have much discriminative ability at any threshold.

Here is some R code. Run it after @Calimo's code which shows how to create the `cut_roc` object.

```r
par(pty = "s") # Make this ROC plot square
plot(cut_roc, print.thres = "best", print.thres.best.method = "youden")
```

[image]

```r
par(pty = "m") # Reset the `pty` parameter
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: thank you so much.  Is it possible to fit the x-axis and also maybe show 1-specificity?

Comment: That's what a ROC curve is: We plot specificity on the x-axis and sensitivity on the y-axis. I'm not sure what you mean by fit the x axis.

Comment: @
dipetkov you are right, That is true. I can fix it. I meant to have the x-axis in the range from 1 to 0. Now does not look nice by looking into the diagonal line.